# Unity3D C# Scaling a shader

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vertex-shader

I want my shader to scale with most likely vertexes but I can't find anything that works...
I have a standard unlit shader.

I have tried a few tutorials or other stuff but they use shader graphs and I'm trying to code it.

Anyone can help me out a bit?

Comment: you should probably add some code examples, and/or links on what you have tries so far so people better understand your issue and what you're trying to achieve